# Multiple Voting on Advertisements

Tags: bug, advertising

Yes, *Another* Advertisement question.

I noticed that, after voting on an advertisement, and after waiting awhile, I was able to vote again for the exact same advertisement, and so every time I came across it.

So, does it negate the previous votes, or allow for an unlimited amount of votes? I mean, I don't really see much harm coming from this, but a rude person could downvote ads over and over.

Comment: If you can only vote while logged in, then I would imagine that voting overwrites the previous vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try and provide the clearest answer I can.

Each ad campaign can have multiple flights (placements with different targets). The vote is specific to the flight that the ad was served from. When you downvote an ad, it will no longer show within that flight.

However, if the same ad is in 10 different flights, you may be served the ad 10 times and need to downvote each time.